# DateFomat give unparsable date error?

Tags: java, date, date-format

if I have a string date:

```
2013-11-14T00:00:00.000
```

What date format can I use to create a date with the offset?

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS Z");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date date = dateFormat.parse(myDate);
```

The above gives an unparsable date error.

Comment: Try dropping the `Z` from the format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

Use `SSS` for milliseconds and remove `Z` as the date string does not have a time zone.

If you intend to print/log the date in another format (with a custom time zone, for example), you will have to use another instance of `DateFormat`:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"  // to parse the date string
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" // to format the date object
```

Comment: how do i get the parsed date with the offset value as a long?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: if I have parsed the date `String` it gives me a `Date` object, if I get the milliseconds it gives a representation of the date as a long. But that doesn't include the offset. I need the `Date` as a long with the offset.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you. A `Date` object represents number of milliseconds relative to epoch (`January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`). It does not have any information about time zones. You can however *format* the date object to see how it looks in a particular time zone (and format).

Answer (score 2):

The `.000` on the end is not a time zone designation; it looks like milliseconds.  Try replacing the `Z` time zone designation with [`SSS` for milliseconds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

Comment: Sorry, that is a typo, the date format is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS Z.

Comment: Ok, but you still need to remove the `Z`.

Comment: But I want the offset.

Comment: There is no offset specified in the string value you gave.

Answer (score 0):

your supplied `2013-11-14T00:00:00.000` is not specified with the above pattern: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS Z"` as sample valid input for this pattern would be:

```
2013-11-14T00:00:00.000 -0700
```

Either drop the `Z` or pass a string as the mentioned sample.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, here is that same kind of code using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

Joda-Time uses that kind of [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format as its default. No need for a formatter to parse that string. Merely pass the string to a `DateTime` constructor. The constructor automatically invokes a built-in ISO formatter.

```
String input = "2013-11-14T00:00:00.000";

// Specify a time zone rather than rely on default.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, timeZone );

System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2013-11-14T00:00:00.000+01:00
```

If you need a java.util.Date for use with other classes, convert from Joda-Time.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```